# Reducing Akamai count hits by changing Mime type

Tags: php, magento, nginx, mime-types, akamai

We're working on reducing the hits Akamai records at the moment. One of the suggestions given by an outside contractor was to change the mime type of the html page.

`Every instance of text/html on a web page generates a page view in Akamai`

Proposed solution is to `Remove or replace the mime type from text/html to text/JSON or other mime type.`

The problem is that if I make the php application to set the mime type to **text/json** or the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) rectified * application/json* most browsers interpret the page as a text file and html is not rendered by their engines.

Any ideas?

Comment: since akami only has 12 followers you may get better support else where

Comment: Any ideas for what? If you're serving html page - it should be `text/html`, if you're serving JSON - it should be `application/json`

Comment: PS: curious, why didn't you ask an outside contractor how to deal with his weird advice?

Comment: i think u need a proper expiration header

Comment: @zerkms That was my understanding also, html gets `text/html` and so on. I gave the contractor the benefit of the doubt, maybe they knew something I did not. After extensive goggling into the suggested course of action, there was no clear discussion of this anywhere. So I thought I would hit up Stack Overflow. Looks like more and more it was just plain old snake oil. Funnily enough, the contractors had no comment to my questions in regards to the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're post is pretty vague.

By reducing hits, do you mean reducing the hits to origin e.g. improve caching?

Or do you mean...hits recorded in the Luna Control panel?

Either way, changing the mime type is not going to do anything in regards to reducing hits.